# creating numbered objects from a constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a constructor that makes squares.

I would like my code to automatically create squares from this constructor using loops and name them square1, square2, square3 ect.

eg.

```
for (n=1; n < x; n++){
var square(n) = new Square();
}
```

Is this possible?

If so how and how do I refer to them in a loop - like square(n)?

I'm new to programming, oop and javascript so sorry if this is really ovb.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

That's what Arrays are for:

```
var squares = new Array();
for (var n = 1; n < x; n++) {
    squares.push( new Square() );
}
```

Now you're able to access them with their zero-based index:

```
squares[0].someMethod(); // etc..
```

To iterate over all the squares in that array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].someMethod();
}
```

Comment: You can simply use `squares.push(...)` to append a new element.

Comment: so squares is an array full of objects that are all called Square each refered to by the array index?

Comment: Essentially yes - the objects don't have a name (but an index instead), and they all are instances of the Square constructor.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty nasty idea. Use an array for this purpose:

```
var squares = [];
for (var n = 1; n < x; n++) {
    squares.push(new Square());
}
```

Anyway, if you really want to do it:

```
window['square' + n] = new Square();
```

This will create globals. There is no clean, `eval`-less way to create locals like that.